# Why does route requirements works for my first route and not for my second one?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I got this issue :

My first route disallow me of using any character that isn't a number (from the regex), this is perfectly working (tell me if you need screen of the result)

But the second one let me use any character as an id, I don't get why, I've tried clearing cache (and many other things) but it stills allow me to use alpha characters.

I have theses two routes currently :

```php
<?php
// src/Controller/AdvertController.php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Twig\Environment;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

/**
 * @Route("/advert")
 */
class AdvertController extends AbstractController
{
  /**
   * @Route("/{page}", name="oc_advert_index", requirements={"page" = "\d+"}, defaults={"page" = 1})
   */
  public function index(Environment $twig, $page)
  {
    $content = $twig->render('Advert/index.html.twig', ['page' => $page, 'name' => 'alex']);

    return new Response($content);
  }


  /**
   * @Route("/view/{id}", name="oc_advert_view", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
   */
  public function view(Environment $twig, $id)
  {
    $content = $twig->render('Advert/view.html.twig', ['id' => $id, 'name' => 'alex']);

    return new Response($content);
  }
}
```

My templates are basic Twig templates (displaying either "id" or "page")
I've tried to look for hidden space and something but I can't find where is the difference (excluding the names "id" and "page")

EDIT1 : here what's I got when executing `php bin/console router/match /advert/view/abc`:

```sh
 [OK] Route "oc_advert_view" matches                                                                                    


+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                   |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | oc_advert_view                                          |
| Path         | /advert/view/{id}                                       |
| Path Regex   | #^/advert/view/(?P<id>[^/]++)$#sDu                      |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     |
| Method       | ANY                                                     |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                               |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _controller: App\Controller\AdvertController::view      |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler |
|              | utf8: true                                              |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

It seems that the "Requirements" are not detected/used for some reason, does someone know why ?

EDIT2: Here what I got when doing `php bin/console router:match /advert/123`

```sh
 [OK] Route "oc_advert_index" matches                                           


+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                   |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | oc_advert_index                                         |
| Path         | /advert/{page}                                          |
| Path Regex   | #^/advert(?:/(?P<page>\d+))?$#sDu                       |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     |
| Method       | ANY                                                     |
| Requirements | page: \d+                                               |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _controller: App\Controller\AdvertController::index     |
|              | page: 1                                                 |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler |
|              | utf8: true                                              |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here we can see that it detects the regex, it feels like this is a typo error but I have copy/pasted at least 3 times, very weird :/

---

FINAL EDIT: 
Thank you to every person who tried to find the issue, I learned a few things so I am very thankful (and sorry for the time waste^^)

Comment: could there be another route that matches view/abc ?

Comment: `bin/console debug:router` command could help to find if there is another route matching `/advert/view/{id}`

Comment: I have never seen a route for the class. why do you have one `@Route("/advert")` ?
You dont want to inject `Environment $twig` rather you can render the template directly like `return $this->render('Advert/view.html.twig', ['id'=>$id]);`
You better create a controller class with the use of maker bundle `make:controller`

Comment: Adding to what @vstelmakh proposed, try `bin/console router:match /advert/view/abc` to easily find which route matches. Then you don't necessarily have to go through the whole list.

Comment: @Theva the `@Route("/advert)` on the Controller will create a prefix for all other routes inside the controller, so `@Route("/view/{id}")` will match with `/advert/view/id`. Injecting the Twig-environment is fine as well with newer Symfony versions. You are right though, since the Controller extends AbstractController, you can use convenience methods like `$this->render()` instead, but it is not mandatory and it is unlikely to be the source of the problem.

Comment: @dbrumann Thanks for the explanation

Here something strange when executing bin/console router:match /advert/view/abc
(putting in EDIT1 cause it's unreadable here)

Comment: That is really odd. Not that it should matter, but have you tried using `:` instead of `=` inside the dictionary? Like this: `requirements={"id": "\d+"}`. Does the debug command recognize the other route's requirements?

Comment: I just tried with ":" and it keeps displaying "NO CUSTOM" for the requirements, the same as with "="

Comment: Finally found the issue, the route was duplicated in config/routes.yaml
I feel dumb but at least we got it

Comment: Would suggest to post solution that you found as an answer. And mark it as resolved. This could help someone else in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED : There were conflicts between config/routes.yaml and my routes, I had to delete the duplicated route. (I followed a course where we first declare it in config/routes.yaml and then we declare routes with annotations, forgot the step of deleting content of config/routes.yaml)

Thank you to every person who tried to find the issue, I learned a few things so I am very thankful (and sorry for the time waste^^)